# How Can I Stop HTTPS Redirection in .net 7 on development machine?

Tags: ssl, .net-core, .net-7.0

My development environment's SSL chain is a hot mess (a whole other problem dealt with elsewhere).

As a result, I'm trying to set up my apps to run in HTTP mode.

I've commented out the call to redirect in Program.cs, like this...

```
    app
        .UseSwagger()
        .UseSwaggerUI();

    app
        //.UseHttpsRedirection() TODO: Do NOT Re-Enable until set to only work when not running on Local (Not sure how yet)
        .UseStaticFiles()
        .UseSerilogRequestLogging() // Listing this after `UseStaticFiles` prevents logging every request for a file.
        .UseAuthorization();
```

I have changed the http port used in `launchSettings.json` to a different one so it wouldn't be stuck on old behaviour to rule that out.

It's STILL redirecting. This `wget` call shows it most clearly.
[image]

How do I stop it trying to redirect to an HTTPS endpoint that's neither there or supported?

I am assuming at this point that it's quite possible that .net 7 has made `UseHttpsRedirection` a default in it's magic setup that it seems to do these days. How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use HSTS? If yes, then you should probably turn it off too.

Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu) of how to turn off some features when an app is not in production mode.

```
using System.Net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.PermanentRedirect;
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
    });
}

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```